# Should requesting examples be tagged as Soft-questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging, soft-question

Here is the description of the tag "soft question":

`For questions that don't admit a definitive answer but still are relevant to this site. Please be specific about what you are after.`

I am wondering if a question is asking for an example, whether it should be tagged as "soft question" or not. It seems to me yes because usually examples are not unique, there is (usually) more than one answers and thus no "a definitive answer". For example, if I ask

`What is an example of a group which is not abelian but metaabelian?`

Should the question be tagged as "soft question"?

Answer (score 8):

Every mathematical statement can be proved in more than one way, so there is no unique answer to anything posted on the site.  The real issue is whether answers can be objectively evaluated as correct or incorrect;  I believe this is what  the description of [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) is actually trying to say.

The tag [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) should not be used here. Use [examples-counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples-counterexamples) and most importantly, a tag for the subject area of the question (e.g., [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory)).

Comment: "The real issue is whether answers can be objectively evaluated as correct or incorrect". I love this description! It is very clear and I would suggest it being added to the description of the tag "soft-question".

Comment: It has been bothering me for a long time that the description of [tag:soft-question] was incorrect and that the tag is frequently applied to questions that are not at all soft.  I have changed the tag wiki excerpt along the lines you suggest.

Comment: Just the first few examples I saw this morning: [Heat equation on manifold](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046370/heat-equation-on-manifold) / [Is there a general notion of orientability, e.g. for the rationals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042807/) / [Can every basic concept of fundamental group be generalized to homotopy group?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041711/) / [Can an empty set be both torsion and torsion free group?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039353)

Comment: I retagged a couple of those.